# How to control DLLs files inside project?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, version-control, source-control-explorer

We re working with GIT. We have a problem with control with the versions of DLL files. Sometimes one person work on dll version 12.0.0, and he want to install new version of this file into only to 8 projects (we have 10 projects inside one solution). After this he pushing new files int repo. Our compilator man when he pulling from repo and compiling the files, has older DLLs version (example 12.0.0 not the newer installed). Our exe file require newer version than 12.0.0, but inside directory we have 12.0.0 version.
How can we control this inside visual studio or inside another application?

Comment: Try to use nuget in order to deliver DLL to the target project. 
You can use nuget.org or deploy your own nuget server (in this case you would need to add URL of this server to the nuget settings).

Comment: Just a reminder that VS downloads all nuget packages BEFORE build so you should not have any troubles with it anymore. BTW, don't save DLL in GIT repo. This is bad practice.

Comment: yea i know. but .after pulling files, clean the solution, rebuild the solution, old DLLs inside my HDD didnt change the version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One of our worker updated a .dll files inside project. After this other workers pulling changesets from repository. When they are rebuilding applications, they get an exception. We wasting a lot of time when we looking for a problem. (dll isnt correct). How we can control dlls' versions?